# Ubuntu 17.4 not reachable over lan after login

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ip, local-area-network, bug

I'm hosting a website on nginx to upload/download zip files over LAN.

I switched to Nginx and Ubuntu 17.4 and there worked too but just for a minute, then the server become not reachable for any PC on LAN or vice versa.

if I type the *local IP* on the browser of any PC over LAN it doesn't work (it take too long to load and in the end it drops the connection)

All **domains and websites hosted** there and the **public IP works** perfectly.

**Update 1**

It was caused by a network bug on ubuntu 17.4
https://askubuntu.com/questions/906103/lan-not-working-on-17-04

**Update 2**

Every time I restart the OS in the login screen it works. When I login as *user* or *root* it doesn't work.

*Temporary fix: I have to go to Nextwork Connections delete the current connection and create a new one every time I login*

Comment: Need far more context on this.

* Why are you transferring data via a LAN using a Web Server/Proxy?
* What kind of files are you transferring?
* What is your network topology?
* What is the nginx config for the internal webserver?

Many questions :)

Comment: A timeout usually points to a firewall issue.